# Assets in Rails. How to minimize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I pin my assets in application.html.erb such:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag("scripts.js") %>
```

But when I look in  later, it includes and `scripts.js` and `application.js`. Double time. How can I fix it and how can I put all my JS or CSS files into application.js(.css) without other files in `<head>` part?

Comment: Read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline) article. Seems you don't understand how Asset Pipeline works.

Comment: Do you call "application.js" too in your layout ? If you call <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> that contain "//= require_tree .", it will call automatically all js files of assets/javascripts folder. 

So if you call <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> (with a require tree) and <%= javascript_include_tag("scripts.js") %>; scripts.js will be call two times !

Delete require tree from your application.js or don't call manually your js file

Comment: @John but what about assets.rb? Must I add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( dropzone.js )` to it or not?

Answer (score 0):

Your `scripts.js` is required twice.

- 1 time from the `require_tree .` in your `application.js`
- 1 time from your `javascript_include_tag("scripts.js")`

Remove one of them and your `scripts.js` will be called once.

Moreover, if you want to load only one js file (`application.js`), just remove your `javascript_include_tag` and your compiled `application.js` will contain the javascript from `scripts.js`. (*It's the same for CSS*)

[More documentation here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline)

Comment: I did it. In my application.html.erb no one CSS including, but in the web page <head> here are again a lot of `<link href>` links. Is it normal???